# KerasTuner RandomSearch throws error 'HyperParameters' object has no attribute 'dtype'

Tags: python, keras

I have been programming a CNN in Keras and I am trying to tune the batch size by using RandomSearch, my code is the following:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from tensorflow import keras
import tensorflow as tf
from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from kerastuner.tuners import RandomSearch
from kerastuner.engine.hyperparameters import HyperParameters

def cnn(X,y):
    number_of_features=X.shape[1]
    number_class=2
    batch_size=256
    epochs=10
    x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test=train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.1,random_state=0)
    
    model=Sequential()
    
    model.add(Dense(1024,activation="relu",input_shape=(number_of_features,))) 
    model.add(Dropout(0.3))
    model.add(Dense(1024,activation="relu"))
    model.add(Dropout(0.3))
    model.add(Dense(number_class,activation="softmax"))
    print(model.summary())
            
    tune(model)

def tune(model):
    hp = HyperParameters()
    hp.Choice('batch_size', values=[16, 32, 64, 128, 256], default=32)
    model.compile(loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy",optimizer=tf.optimizers.Adam(),metrics=["accuracy"])
    tuner = RandomSearch(
        model,
        hyperparameters=hp,
        objective="val_accuracy",
        max_trials=5,
        executions_per_trial=3
    )
```

I have tried different solutions found on the web, but I still have the following error:

```
'HyperParameters' object has no attribute 'dtype'
```

My code works fine until I try to tune the hyperparameters. Am I missing something?